# AWS SES verification failed for AWS Route 53 domain

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, godaddy-api, amazon-simple-email-service

I recently bought a domain from godaddy.com but transferred it to AWS Route 53. The transfer is successful but I cannot verify my domain for AWS SES even though Verification and DKIM name, Type and value are the same. I tried to verify many times but every time it failed. What might have happened? Thanks.

Comment: when you resolve the text record for your own machine, does . it get resolve ? dig _amazonses.domain.com txt ? Do you get the txtvalue ?

Comment: Hi James Dean! Thank you for your reply. No, it does not get resolved. Thanks

Comment: It means your nameservers are not correct, what do you get when you run "dig domain.com +trace" --> Nameservers or NS , do they match of what you see in Route53 hosted zone ?

Comment: No @JamesDean they do not match. How can I fix this issue can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Get the NS which is showing in R53 hosted zone and paste it the place mentioned here (assuming you have transferred domain to Route53)  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

Comment: Thank you so much @JamesDean. I did the change in R53 hosted zone but while performing "dig domainname.com SOA" I get "status: SERVFAIL" what is the cause for it and how to fix it? Thank you.